# Get the verbose_name of a related field in a QuerySet

Tags: django

It's possible to loop through `objects.model._meta._fields()` to get the verbose name of a field:

```
objects = Foo.objects.all()
objects.model._meta._fields()[1].verbose_name
```

How can I do the same for fields in the models that `Foo` has a foreign key to?

**EDIT:**

It's possible to do this:

```
model = models.get_model('app', 'Foo')
model._meta._fields()[1].verbose_name
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have an API endpoint that feeds a js data grid. And I want to dynamically create column names on the server side for it.